# Angle Between 2 Objects

Tags: java, game-maker

In a game engine known as Game Maker Studio, there is a function called `point_angle(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.
https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/vector%20functions/point_direction.html

This function returns the angle between 2 objects (see the image). How would I recreate this function in java?

---

Additionally, after I find the angle, I have this class:

**Class**

```
int velX = 0, velY = 0;

public void tick() {
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
}
```

The `tick()` method runs along with this game loop (in case it is important):

```
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
double delta = 0;
long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
int updates = 0;
int frames = 0;
while(running){
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
    lastTime = now;
    while(delta >= 1){
        tick();
        updates++;
        delta--;
    }
    render();
    frames++;

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
        timer += 1000;
        System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
        frames = 0;
        updates = 0;
    }
}
```

How will I modify `velX` and `velY` so in a way that replicates the function `point_direction(x1, y1, x2, y2)` in Game Maker Studio?

Thank you for your time.

PS: I am trying to recreate the example code shown in the link above

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the angle function is actually quite simple. Using the function [`Math.atan2(y, x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) you can get the angle from the x-axis to a coordinate.

[image: Angle from x-axis to point]

This calculation only works for one point relative to the origin. So we need to translate the second objects coordinates to be relative to the origin before doing the angle calculation.

[image]

Here is some example pseudocode:

```
function angle(point1, point2) {
    translatedPoint = point2 - point1
    angle = atan2(translatedPoint.y, translatedPoint.x)
    return angle
}
```

This result will be in radians, so if you want degrees you have to convert it to that.

This is more complicated than it needs to be for your use-case. You are not using angles to represent your movement. The easiest way to do this is to just take the second point minus the first point, then you get a vector going from the first point to the second one. If you normalize this vector (make the length one) you get the direction from the first to the second point.

```
function dirTo(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    newX = x2 - x1
    newY = y2 - y1

    // normalize the vector
    dirX = newX / sqrt(newX * newX + newY * newY)
    dirY = newY / sqrt(newX * newX + newY * newY)
    
    return (dirX, dirY)
}
```

The direction vector can now be multiplied with some scalar (in your case the speed) and there you have your `velX` and `velY`

Comment: `This is more complicated than it needs to be for your use-case. You are not using angles to represent your movement.` - Well yes, but I need this angle to work out the direction a bullet is going to have to move in when the player shoots. The player shoots wherever the mouse is pointing at, and the bullet doesn't stop until it hits something. Any suggestions to make it simpler then?

Comment: I think the same thing would work in this case too. Calculate the vector from the player to the mouse, normalize it and use it as your direction. Unless you actually need the rotation to rotate a sprite or something, then using the rotation might make sense.

Comment: Actually I need the rotation for both determining bullet trajectory and rotating a sprite. I have a vector now, how would I change that into an angle to rotate a sprite at?

Comment: In my answer I go through the process of taking a vector and turning it into an angle. Is there something else you are asking i don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I tried `System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(mx - x, my - y)));` and it gave me some unexpected values. However it works and gives the appropriate direction. Unless my understanding is incorrect, angles in degrees in java is 0° on the x axis, with increasing angles counter clockwise? Either way, the values I obtained from my tests don't make sense. I would like to understand why I don't get 0° on the x axis, with increasing values counter clockwise?

Comment: You are doing `Math.atan2(x, y)` while the method defines `Math.atan(y, x)`